# wpf disable on lost focus

Tags: wpf, textbox, focus

I have a simple wpf application that consists of 3 textboxes (tx1, tx2 and tx3).

Depending on the content of tx1, I would like to disable either tx2 or tx3.
I do this check in tx1_LostFocus and set tx2.IsEnabled or tx3.IsEnabled to False.

When disabling tx3 all works fine, the cursor goes to tx2.

But disabling tx2 results not in seeing my cursor in tx3, it is simply not visible.

I think the core of the problem is setting tx2.IsEnabled = False in tx1_LostFocus.

But I am forced to do this in the lost focus event.

Any clue?

Comment: create a converter to do the job

Comment: could you give more details how to do this with a converter?

Comment: To do this using `Converter` you need to create an `AttachedProperty` for `Enabling` a `Disabling` your `TextBox` based on other `TextBoxes` Then you can use `Converter` to to make it `Enabled`/ `Disabled` based on `condition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did some quick tests and it looks like a control can receive focus even if it is not enabled.  I added these lines in the `LostFocus` event handler for `textOne`:

```
Debug.Print(b.Name + " lost focus.");
Debug.Print("Disabling " + this.textTwo.Name);
```

and this line in the `GotFocus` event handler for `textTwo`

```
Debug.Print("Enabling " + this.textTwo.Name);
```

You can see in the output window that when I tab out of `textOne` `textTwo` does get focus even though it is disabled:

> textOne lost focus.
>
> Disabling textTwo
>
> textTwo got focus.

I think the best solution is to manually set focus after disabling the controls.  Something like this:

```
if (testCondition)
{
    tx2.IsEnabled = false;
    tx3.Focus();
}
else
{
    tx3.IsEnabled = false;
    tx2.Focus();
}
```

## Better Solution

I like this solution better because it is not brittle.  It is not going to introduce strange tabbing behavior if you reorder your controls or change your condition logic.  In the `GotFocus` event handler for `tx2` you can add this code to force focus to move to the next control if `tx2` is disabled:

```
if (!tx2.IsEnabled)
{
    tx2.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution. <br/><br/>But I have a another question:<br/> In the scenario above, imagine I would like to make tx2 disabled or enabled depending on the content of tx1. <br/>Say: even numbers in tx1 should disable tx2, and uneven numbers should enable tx2. <br/><br/>- Now when I first enter "0" in tx1, tx2 is disabled and focus goes correctly to tx3. - Now I tab back to tx1 and enter "1". I would expect tx2 becoming enabled and focus my go to tx2, but it first goes to tx3 (and tx2 is enabled after leaving tx1)

Comment: @klawusel - I guess it probably depends on when you enable `tx2`.  If you enable it after `tx1` loses focus then it is probably too late at that point.  I would imagine the focus manager has already picked `tx3` as the next focus target (my tests confirm this).  Can you enable/disable your controls before the `tx1` loses focus.  That would solve all of your problems, I think.

Comment: which event is fired in this moment? I did not find validate or something similar, and PreviewLostFocus does not work

Comment: In the `TextChanged` event?  That might be a little annoying for the user, though.

Comment: You can just take my second solution and add it to the `GotFocus` event handler of both `tx2` and `tx3`.  When `tx2` gets focus if it is not enabled then set focus to `tx3` and vice versa.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the last proposal: both tx2 and tx3 are enabled after tx1 with content = "1" lost the focus, but the cursor goes to tx3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93177/discussion-between-klawusel-and-jason-boyd).

Answer (score 0):

Use `tx3.Focus();` when you need to focus the cursor on it at the end of tx1_LostFocus.
Don't forget to enable tx2 if tx3 is disabled, and vice-versa.

Comment: problem is that I have thousands of routines that come from vb6 and there I do not have anything to do but disabling tx2 on leaving tx1 to get the cursor automatically in tx3 !!

Comment: maybe providing us your code would help us to figure it out